# Inconsistent problem with Android

Tags: android, database, platform

I have a very strange problem.

I have an xml file of four data structures:
A with data and collection of B.
B with data and collection of C.
C with data and collection of D.
D with data.

Collection is made by providing an ID of upper structure in each structure. I.e. D has an ID of one C.

So I parse this xml file and store all the data in the SQLite database. Afterwards I load all the data from database and make objects (accordingly to A B C D structures)

At some point of execution I need to find specific object D of an object A. Which means:
I need to find specific object B of a given object A. I filter all Bs and find the right B. Then I filter Cs of that B and find the right C. After that I filter Ds of that C and find what I need.

To make a more clear picture of what is this all about:
I have a location with specific date (starting from January 1st and ending at December 31) intervals where every date interval has specific day intervals (00:00 - 23:59) and each day interval have messages which needs to be presented. That forms my A B C D structure.

At this point I don't believe I have written some kind of buggy code because everything is pretty simple: Parsing xml, saving data in the tables, loading data from database and creating objects.

But, when I test my application on different phones, on some of the phones I miss some data. I.e. it works great on HTC Magic 1.5, but gives no results on SGS 2.3.3. 
I don't know how many times I checked everything and can't find the error. And of course I tried cleaning/rebuilding my project many times. It just seems that it's related to different versions of Android platform.

Any idea where I should look for problems in my application? Is there something regarding platform implementation that I should be aware of? Any help would be appreciated!

I guess the summary of this problem would be a question like this:
Why my data exists on one phone and doesn't exist on another one?

Comment: Have you tried getting SQLite DB files off of both devices and checking what they hold (after XML file(s) are parsed and loaded)? This could clarify if XML parsing is identical on both devices. The only other place I suspect could be causing this inconsistency is SQLite db engine itself. Check SQLite version on htc magic 1.5 and sgs 2.3.3 and see if there were any breaking changes.

Comment: I have found out that problem is regarding parsing... It seems that xml parser cuts some data when parsing. I.e. instead of ID 96 I have 6. I had some similar problems earlier where instead of latitude/longitude for example 55.123456 I was receiving only 23456, last numbers... So I'll try to update my parser implementation to handle these bugs. One more reason not to like Android platform I guess... Anyway, thanks for your suggestions.